# how to ignore duplicates in postgres with executemany in version 9.414?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.4

I am working with postgres 9.414. I am aware of "on conflict" command in insert command, but its supported only on version 9.5 and above. Any workaround for below that, such as  I can take care of inserting many elements at a go using `executemany` from python?

My executemany block:

```
db_cursor.executemany('''insert into "tablename" ("col1","col2")''', data)
```

data: list of all values in tuples `[('val11','val12'),('val21', 'val22'), ('val31', 'val32')]` to be inserted.

Thanks a lot,
Sudip

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicate first from the list of tuples by converting it to set.
Then you can run command excecutemany:

```
list(set([('val11','val12'),('val21', 'val22'), ('val31', 'val32')]))
```

Now you have everything unique in list of tuples.

Comment: The issue with that is, although there is uniqueness within the new set of data, but it doesnt protect if the data is already in the table.

Comment: okay so you want to check if data is already exists or not. Right?

Comment: Nopes, I want to avoid duplicate records during insertion.